# Styling p-selectButton

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a p-selectButton tag, which I need to edit its styling. Here come my HTML and CSS codes:

```
<p-selectButton class="pSelectButtonStyle" [options]="myTags" > </p-selectButton>

.pSelectButtonStyle {
  border-top-left-radius: .3em;
  border-top-right-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;
  border-left: solid #cccccc .07em;
  border-right: solid #cccccc .07em;
}
```

The result of applyig the CSS class looks like the above image.
[image]

I need to have border on the corners, too. Can you help me with this?

Comment: `border: solid #cccccc .07em;` - this will add all borders, at the moment you are just setting left and right borders, so not sure where the top and bottom come from. Also, you can combine border radius to `border-radius: .3em;` since you are using same value for all 4 corners

Comment: you need to add style in global style.css file please check below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a third party library then you can not modify the style at the component level. So here  you need to place your style in global stylesheet i.e style.css file like below using `p-selectButton` class selector

**html**

```
<div class="my-container" >
<p-selectButton [options]="myTags" > </p-selectButton>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.ui-buttonset:not(.ui-splitbutton) .ui-button {
  border-top-left-radius: .3em;
  border-top-right-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: .3em;
  border-left: solid #cccccc .07em;
  border-right: solid #cccccc .07em;
  background: white;
}
```

**[Here is Solution on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1ssbh?file=src%2Fstyles.css)**